# How to target Facebook audience for Google

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, ads, digital

If I am running a Facebook ad and after some day I'll run a Google display ad. So I want to target Facebook existing customer for Google ads. In this scenario my display ad will be showed to the Facebook existing customer. So how to do this. Please explain me all process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254567/20153035) for Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to see what this site is all about, and consider checking the [Stack Exchange sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to find a site that would be more fitting towards your question.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting a Facebook audience entails selecting a specific group of Facebook users based on demographics, interests, behaviours, and other criteria in order to show them relevant content or advertisements. Facebook provides advertisers with a variety of targeting options to help them reach the most relevant audience for their campaigns.

Advertisers can target Facebook users by age, gender, location, interests, job titles, relationship status, education level, and other factors. Advertisers can maximise the effectiveness of their campaigns, reach the people who are most likely to be interested in their products or services, and improve their return on investment by targeting the right audience (ROI).

Follow these steps to target a Facebook audience for Google:

- Create a Facebook custom audience: To begin, create a Facebook custom
  audience by selecting the desired targeting criteria such as
  location, demographics, interests, behaviours, and more. This will
  generate a list of people who match your target demographic.
- Export the Facebook audience: After creating the custom audience on
  Facebook, export the list as a CSV or TXT file.
- Log in to your Google Ads account and go to the Audience Manager to
  upload the audience. Make a new audience and then select "Upload your
  own data." Upload the previously exported Facebook custom audience
  list.
- Create a Google Ads campaign: Now that your Facebook custom audience
  has been uploaded to Google, you can create a new Google Ads campaign
  and select the custom audience as your targeting option.
- Optimize your campaign: As your campaign runs, track its performance
  and make changes to improve it. Track conversions and other metrics
  with tools like Google Analytics and adjust your targeting, ad copy,
  and bidding strategy accordingly.

Following these steps will allow you to effectively target your Facebook audience on Google, increasing your reach and driving more conversions.